# Exchange 2010 - reset OWA language and time zone

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-access

Is it possible to reset a user or all users (or to have a user do it for themselves) so that when they log in to OWA 2010, they are presented with the language and time zone settings page (the one that you get when you log in to OWA 2010 for the first time)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When a user logs into OWA/OWAP, the user can change the *Language* and *Date and Time Formats* settings under *Options* that is located at the top right side of the window (next to the user's name) then go to *Regional Settings*.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the info but I should have been more specific in my question.  What I want to figure out is how to reset OWA so that when a user logs on, they are prompted with the Language / Date and Time page.  I'm sure that the system stores attribute(s) somewhere to keep track of this.  Question is, what are those attribute(s) and can they be reset so that the system thinks the user is logging in to OWA for the first time?